# How to find out the start commit of a branch?

Tags: git

From Version Control with Git by Loeliger, 2ed,

> Because **the original commit from which a branch was started** is not explicitly identified,
>   that commit (or its equivalent) can be found algorithmically using the name of the
>   original branch from which the new branch forked:
>
> ```
> git merge-base original-branch new-branch
> ```

- Is it correct that in a repository's graph representation, a branch is a path of commits?
- if looking a graph of a repository, with a branch name pointing to the tip of each branch, but without showing the start commit of each branch, how do you find out the start commit of each branch?

Answer (score 5):

> if looking a graph of a repository, with branch names pointing to some commits as the tips of branches, how do you find out the start commit of each branch?

```
git log --graph --decorate

// To get the same display as in the image below add the --oneline as well
git log --graph --decorate --oneline
```

[image]

Comment: I believe the screenshot you attached is actually `git log --oneline --graph --decorate`

Comment: Thanks. (1) Do you have descriptions for the legends used in the output? I am especially not clear about the purposes of different colors. How do you tell which commits are the start and end commits of each branch? (2) In the first two merges, why are there no branch names for the merged branches? (3) My question is more about, finding out the start commit of each branch, given a graph representation of a repository with branch names pointing to the tips of the branches. I assume the start commits are not shown by the graph.

Comment: You can use the colors or to write your own script to set any color you wish. `git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative` this is a sample on how to checnge colors and write your custom logger output

Comment: Thanks. But  my three-part questions remain. For my third part, I want to add that your command is helpful, (which is why I upvoted),  although I am not clear how to read its output and I would like to know how one can find out himself without the output telling you the start commits.

Comment: The yellow colors are the branches pointing to the commit which the branch is pointing now if you will check it out now

Answer (score 4):

> Is it correct that in a repository's graph representation, a branch is a path of commits?

Maybe.  It depends on what you mean by both "branch" and "path" here.  (Do you mean the graph-theoretic "path"?  If so, probably "no" since "path" just means any non-empty walk through some nodes and edges without doubling back through a node; although now we need to know what you mean by "branch"...)

> if looking a graph of a repository, with a branch name pointing to the tip of each branch, but without showing the start commit of each branch, how do you find out the start commit of each branch?

You can't, in general.  Here's one fragment of a graph:

```
            B - C
          /       \
... o - A           F - G    <-- br
          \       /
            D - E
```

What's the "start commit" of branch `br`?  Was it `B`, or `A`, or something earlier than `A` (in the `... - o` chain)?  What other branch, if any, did `D` and/or `E` come from?

If there are additional names they may provide enough clues to guess:

```
            B - C
          /       \
... o - A           F - G    <-- br
          \       /
            D - E            <-- newfeature
```

The log messages may also provide clues; the log message for `F` might read `merge branch newfeature into br` for instance.  In this case probably `D` was the "starting commit" for branch `newfeature` and whoever made commit `F` made it by doing `git merge newfeature` while on branch `br`.  The origin of `br` is therefore probably pre-`A`.

Reflogs may also provide these kinds of clues.

However, except for the log message, any of these other clues might vanish.  Once `newfeature` is merged in, we can delete the name (and its reflog); and reflog entries expire after 90 days by default (or 30 days if the object to which they point is unreachable from the tipmost object).

On the other hand, that same graph might have come about in a different way:

```
            B - C
          /       \
... o - A           F - G    <-- br
          \       /
            D - E            <-- origin/br
```

The start point of `origin/br` is probably the same as the start point of `br`, and the merge `F` happened when someone did a `git merge` (perhaps as part of a `git pull`) to combine his/her work with someone else's work.  Both users were working on their own `br` branches, sharing some repository or repositories (perhaps a centralized server).

---

When you find yourself asking "what was the first commit on branch X", git encourages you to stop asking (or to ask yourself "why do I care?").

Comment: Thanks. I haven't read your reply to my second question. For your reply to my first question: (1) by "path", I mean it as a concept in graph theory. What do you mean by "walk"? Do you distinguish between a path and a walk?  (2) By "branch", I mean it as a concept in Git. Honestly, I haven't found a definition of a branch that is clear or rigorous. Maybe you can share the definition you found?

Comment: for (1), I read again your def of a walk. Do you mean a branch can  double back through a commit?

Comment: (3) why should I not care what the start commit of a branch is?

Comment: (4) in your graph examples, do you show the branch names for all the branches? If I read the book correctly, branch merging dord not eliminate the operand branches (either the merged branch(es) or the target branch). So I expect to see the branch names of the merged branches.

Comment: Hm, re (1), sorry, I was going back to general graphs (with undirected edges, and maybe even allowing for multigraphs) when saying "walk", which I was using loosely to aim at the usual graph-theoretic meaning of "path".  Since git's commit graph is a DAG you can't return to a node by following the arcs, so there's no problem there.  For (2), there isn't any proper formal definition I can find either.  For (3), I know some people do care, but git doesn't really let you find out, so I'm curious what problem you intend to solve here.  And (running out of space for coment)...

Comment: For item (4), yes, the branch names (the references) do persist until you delete them, but you *can* delete them, people do delete them, and when fetching from other repositories you may not get all names (e.g., you normally don't bring over any refs/remotes/ names) even though you do get all reachable objects.

Comment: By the way, I think perhaps the most useful definition for "branch" in terms of what's in the commit DAG is "everything reachable from a given commit", sometimes modified by "... via the first parent in the case of a merge".  However, this definition means that the "start" of each branch is usually the root commit (it's definitely *a* root commit; there can be multiple roots).  That's why I think git makes looking for a "start point" kind of useless -- we need to look for something else (LCAs, usually).

Comment: Thanks. If branch B is merged into branch A, are both original branch B and original branch A part of the new branch A?

Comment: Using what I called "perhaps the most useful definition", yes: once branch B branch is merged in to A, it's been completely incorporated (B is a subset of or—if fast forward—equal to A, i.e., all commits contained within B are also contained within A).  Note, though, that adding a new commit on B causes the new commit to be contained only in B.